# Netbeans / Svn build-impl.xml:1067 The module has not been deployed

Tags: svn, netbeans, build, module

Apache Netbeans IDE 14
TortoiseSVN 1.14

Scenario 1:
I created/added a new user to our SVN Server so they would be able to access the repository and check out projects. New User is able to check out projects to a folder. User can open up NetBeans and add in the new project with no problems. However, when user tries to run it, it says the build failed. Error message below:

C:\ProjectsPath\ContextName\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1067: The module has not been deployed

Scenario 2:
New User goes into NetBeans, creates a standalone web application, runs it, and there are no problems. It hits our server, localhost page comes up and shows the results.

I've googled around and looked around our settings/properties and I'm just not sure. Would anyone have any insight on this issue? I think it has something to do with the server not recognizing a checked out project under a specific user>??

Comment: Furthermore, the other error that Im getting is Filter mapping specified an unknown filter name <Filter Name>Filter